# Gatsby with imgix

Tags: reactjs, image, gatsby, imgix

I am currently preparing to migrate away from WordPress and I am seriously considering Gatsby.

In WordPress land I use [imgix](https://www.imgix.com/) to offload and process my images and I am interested to understand how to achieve this with Gatsby.

I can't find any documentation that covers using Imgix with Gatsby, although I have found [react-imgix](https://github.com/imgix/react-imgix).

Can I use this with Gatsby?

Can I specify imgix images in the frontmatter of Markdown files using Gatsby?

Any information on the best way to handle external images from imgix in Gatsby would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**2020 Edit:** imgix is working on an official Gatsby plugin which will cover a variety of use cases, including the ones mentioned here. The plugins are located here: https://github.com/imgix/gatsby

---

Gatsby is based on React, and `imgix` have already a plugin for React, so it should work out-of-the-box.

Something different will be if you have to serve your file from your own server, where you will need `gatsby-image` to process it, but in this case, your component will convert to an `<img />` tag with the corresponding `src` string and will work as expected.